# kerberos request ticket server not found in keytab

Tags: apache-2.4, kerberos, single-sign-on, typo3

**TL;DR**

First: my server name is xy.

Second: the domain I logon to is EXAMPLE.COM

Third: this is my apache configuration

```
<Location />
            AuthType Kerberos
            AuthName "Kerberos Login"
            KrbServiceName HTTP
            KrbMethodNegotiate On
            KrbMethodK5Passwd Off
            KrbAuthRealms EXAMPLE.COM
            KrbSaveCredentials On
            KrbVerifyKDC Off
            KrbLocalUserMapping on
            # This has to wait until we get the keytab file
            Krb5Keytab /etc/apache2/satypo3.keytab
            require valid-user
</Location>
```

Fourth: The way I generate the keytab file is like this:

```
ktpass 
   -princ HTTP/chzugsvint001@INFRONT.LOCAL
   -mapuser kerdummy@EXAMPLE.COM
   -crypto AES256-SHA1
   -ptype KRB5_NT_PRINCIPAL
   -pass *PASS*
   -out C:\temp\satypo3.keytab
```

Fifth: My /etc/hosts file contains
    127.0.1.1 xy

Sixth: The error I get when accessing the frontend is the following:

```
[auth_kerb:error] [pid 4809] [client 192.168.3.170:56962] gss_accept_sec_context() failed: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information (, Request ticket server HTTP/xy.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM not found in keytab (ticket kvno 6))
```

So what I don't get is, although I have in no ways specified anything about xy.example.com, Kerberos tries to authenticate the server as this and fails.

Any Ideas?

**Long version:**

I've set up a Apache Kerberos SSO setup as it has been done many times from many of my peers in DevOps over the years and now I'm at this point too.

I've followed quite a bunch of great walkthroughs like [this one](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/ig_ldap_sso_auth/2.1.2/AdministratorManual/ConfigureApacheKerberos.html) and everything seems to work fine until the moment the user tries to log in when the user gets stuck on an infinite loop of login popups. I tried solving the issue like it is described [here](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/ig_ldap_sso_auth/2.1.2/AdministratorManual/ConfigureApacheKerberos.html#admin-manual-kerberos-apache-pitfalls-basic-authentication) just to find out that everything is already set up accurately.

So you are my last hope, please help me Serverfault.

Regards
Tizian

**EDIT** The major code is 000d0000 and the minor code of the error is 96c73a23

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally figured out what seemed to be the problem.

As it seems, the options cannot be activated or disabled by *On* or *Off* but with **on** or **off**.